# How to use spring jdbcTemplate class for dynamoDB?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, spring-data, spring-jdbc

I want to fetch records from DynamoDB table based on search condition and stream it back to the controller layer from repository layer. Do we have any equivalent api method like JDBCTemplate.queryForStream used in RDBMS for DynamoDB?

Comment: DynamoDB Mapper is the closet you can get to JDBC and I don't think it has streams

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB uses a http endpoint for connections. Connections are short lived and not long lived like JDBC.